# Position of whitespace while using text-overflow: ellipsis;

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a top bar for a mobile website which looks like this:
[image]

The user can open a personal menu by clicking his/her name. 
When the name of the person is very long (blue bar) I want to shorten it using `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

I got that to work (looks like the blue bar) but now if I have a short name the arrow icon is shown on the right (red bar). I want to keep the arrow next to the name and the remaining whitespace on the right of the arrow, as in the green bar.

I don't want to set a width or max-width to any of the elements (except maybe the button) because I want it to work on different mobile devices, therefore the available width is unknown.

Is there any way to achieve this with just HTML and CSS? What I have done so far:

HTML

```
<button>Log off</button>
<div id="menu">
    <span id="icon">+</span>
    <span id="name">John Withthelonglastname</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#name {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#icon { float:right;}
button { float: right;}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/webwolfe/L07t0zk7/

Comment: Put the arrow on the left, for consistency :D

Comment: UX came up with this, I'm just trying to build it...

Comment: Don't worry, just kidding

Comment: Use float: left; instead of float: right;

Comment: float:left put it on the absolute left, he doesn't want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with **HTML** and **CSS** by using [Flex](http://html5please.com/#flexbox):

```css
.menu {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.name {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.icon {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
button {
  min-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu blue">
  <span class="name">John Withthelonglastname</span>
  <span class="icon">+</span>
  <button>Log off</button>
</div>

<br>


<div class="menu red">
  <span class="name">John Doe </span>
  <span class="icon">+</span> 
  <button>Log off</button>
</div>
```

Take note of [FlexyBoxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) as a fiddler to play with its settings.

P.S: it is better to use classes instead of IDs for general purpose elements

Comment: Thank you Andrea! This is the only answer that gives me the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You and use content to add in the icon after the name.

```
#name {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#name:after{
    content: ' +';
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I tried this but it doen't seem to work, the icon appears over my button or even out of sight on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sweet `:before` pseudoSelector instead of icon `span`:

```
#name:before
{
content:'+';
z-index:999;
display:inline-block;
float:right
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/L07t0zk7/1/)

Comment: This gives me the exact same result, as my own code (red menu), the icon stiil appears all the way to the right, as you can see in your fiddle. (In Chrome at least, I did not check other browsers)